# Gulp wrong order

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have an Angular project that is supposed to make use of a library called angular-libphonenumber (https://github.com/cwill747/angular-libphonenumber).

I run:

```
bower install --save angular-libphonenumber
```

then:

```
gulp install
```

Now gulp thinks it is a good idea to inject angular-libphonenumber before angular itself:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

How do I tell gulp that this is not a good idea and inject lib-phonenumber after angular?

Here's the inject.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    naturalSort = require('gulp-natural-sort'),
    angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
    bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

var handleErrors = require('./handle-errors');

var config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
    app: app,
    vendor: vendor,
    test: test,
    troubleshoot: troubleshoot
}

function app() {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
            .pipe(naturalSort())
            .pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
}

function vendor() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {
            name: 'bower',
            relative: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return stream;
}
...
```

Comment: How does your gulpfile look? Anyhow, you may be looking for [gulp-angular-filesort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort).

Comment: @SáT: Updated post

Comment: Ah. Well, in my experience gulp-angular-filesort is just broken: we've experienced issues much like [this](https://github.com/klei/gulp-angular-filesort/issues/44). Reversing the output of the plugin may help you, but it's a horrible hack and I'm not sure why it works. Me, I ended up rewriting the plugin.

Comment: I am also fed up with it, I now added the required scripts manually so I won't waste another working day. 

Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's my hastily written, half-assed implementation of the thing: https://gist.github.com/Botffy/e88c174c5fd80bb1fc0493966b7ee795 . Maybe someday I'll get my shit together and create a proper fork.

Comment: @SáT Good luck with that ;)